# Jenkins: Create a pull request on GitHub and merge it to the main branch

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a pipeline to run every hour and check for changes to test. I want it to build and test the project only if new commits have been made (not yet implemented). However, after the tests if they pass, I want to create a pull request from the staging branch that I test from to the main branch and merge the changes.

How would I go about doing this? Here is my pipeline so far:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Pull Source Code') {
            steps {
            
                git branch: "staging", credentialsId: '58315ff7-085f-4213-b071-e0b72ba94ff9', url: 'https://github.com/DevonXDal/Reverse-Makerspace'
            }
        }
        stage('Insert Environment Variables') {
            steps {
            
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: '3d2deb8f-69c5-4d22-a475-0d981a34574d', variable: 'envfile')]) {
                    sh "cp \$envfile ${WORKSPACE}/test.env"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Docker Build'){
            steps{
                sh '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.Test.yml build --no-cache' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test the Project'){
            steps{
                sh '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.Test.yml down || true'
                sh '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.Test.yml up'
                sh 'y || true'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            sh '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.Test.yml down || true'
            sh '/usr/bin/docker image prune -a --filter "until=48h"'
            sh 'y || true'
            sh '/usr/bin/docker volume rm reversemakerspacetesting_db-data-test'
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen a few tutorials that use pull requests that are already open to merge the changes but how can I create a new pull request from the pipeline and merge it?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the git branch name in Jenkins using variable.
By using that variable you can use if condition in your Jenkins pipeline according to your case.

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("your branch name"))
```